# SSL3 issue, decryption failed

Tags: ssl, openssl, installation, ubuntu-14.04, dropbox

The full error msg is following,

```
error:1408F119:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:decryption failed or bad record mac
```

I encountered this issue in two (seemingly) unrelated settings, and wonder if this is a wide spread problem. How to fix it?

First, this happened when installing sublime text, and then when dropbox is trying to start.

On sublime text, i typed,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3;
sudo apt-get update;
sudo apt-get install sublime-text-installer;
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/sublime-text-3/sublime_text /usr/local/bin/sublime;
```

Details of the sublime install process is as follow,

```
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-2/ubuntu/ trusty/main sublime-text all 2.0.2-1~webupd8~3 [9,670 B]
Fetched 9,670 B in 0s (29.1 kB/s)       
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package sublime-text.
(Reading database ... 200988 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../sublime-text_2.0.2-1~webupd8~3_all.deb ...
Downloading...

--2017-06-11 07:50:17--  
https://c758482.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/Sublime%20Text%202.0.2%20x64.tar.bz2
Resolving c758482.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com (c758482.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com)... 23.60.73.100
Connecting to c758482.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com (c758482.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com)|23.60.73.100|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 5662968 (5.4M) [application/x-bzip2]
Saving to: ‘Sublime Text 2.0.2 x64.tar.bz2’
0K ........ ..                                           12% 1.69M=0.4s

2017-06-11 07:50:18 (1.69 MB/s) - Read error at byte 699296/5662968 (error:1408F119:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:decryption failed or bad record mac). Retrying.
```

The dropbox issue is after install from deb file using Ubuntu Software Center, I typed,

```
dropbox start -i
```

I saw,

```
Starting Dropbox...[Errno 1] _ssl.c:1429: error:1408F119:SSL 
routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:decryption failed or bad record mac
```

## Additional Info

This is a new install of ubuntu 14.04. Did a few `apt-get update`, and I've installed Anaconda 4.4.0. Nothing else.

Ubuntu 14.04
OpenSSL 1.0.2l 25 May 2017
Kernel : 3.19.0-33-generic

Comment: Since the problem occurs with multiple sites and also after lots of data were already successfully loaded this might be a hardware error, like a faulty network card. If this is the case the problem should be erratic and not reproducible, i.e. happen from time to time but usually at different positions during the download.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I don't think that's a hardware issue. It's a brand new Dell Precision box (age: 2 wks). It's totally reproducible.

Comment: It happens always on the same position in the same download? Are other URL's except the ones you gave are affected? Is there some local AV installed which might tamper with the connection or some SSL intercepting firewall/proxy? Is this only on this system or also on other systems in the same network?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Quick background : i have three PCs (mac, Win 10, ubuntu) connected to the internet via a consumer grade wifi modem. Been using this modem for ubuntu connection for > 3 yrs. Never had this problem bef. What's different is this is a new install of 14.04 from an Dell image, *and* the same install was working few days ago. See my edits for details.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Does the download always fail on the same position? No, it's rather erratic.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich New update : sublime text finally succeeded. During the install, it suffered from this error twice. So, there seems to be something interrupting the download process? Why?

Comment: There is no OpenSSL 1.0.21 (probably 1.0.2 and some letter) and not kernel 9.19 (probably 4.9.19-...). My guess is still that this is a hardware problem or a firmware problem which corrupts the packets and which  then causes this error because TLS detects modified packets. And it actually does not matter much for such errors if the system is brand new or not - it might even be worse with brand new systems since it is more likely that the hardware or firmware or driver has still bugs in edge cases.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Will talk to dell support Monday. On openssl, it's my bad, should be 1.0.2l (that's a letter 'l', not 1). On kernel, it's my bad again. It should be 3.19.0-33-generic. Can you think of anything software related that could cause such problem? On Win10 and Mac OS X, I have no problem downloading files.

Answer (score -1):

I have a fix, but that leaves any explanation even more mysterious. This problem occurred when I connected to the internet via wifi. (It's a home network without proxy.) The wireless modem (Actiontec C1000A) has been in use for at least a year.

The fix is, not to use wifi, but to connect directly to the modem with a network cable. Once connected, this SSL3 issue disappears.

Since I did not have this problem just few days ago, something might have been changed.

Could someone familiar with wireless technology explain what might have gone wrong.

Comment: This looks for me like hardware failing. There might be various reasons, like the age (especially capacitors tend to age which can cause strange instabilities but other hardware will age too) or maybe it's too hot. I've seen hard disks sporadically failing because of bad cooling.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Here is more details about my config. The Dell ubuntu box is new, but I put in a wifi card, which is suspect since it's about 3 yrs old. To test that, i use another wireless adaptor, which i just bought from amazon. Had exact same problem. So, I'm not sure. But that's surely very strange. Thks for the comment anyway.